# Javascript dynamic variable name (in AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery

For an AJAX post methode (from 30 inputs in total) I thought it could be done way easier to bound the variables for the later PHP handling. But the way I thought it could be done, doesnt work that well..

My javascript code:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    var fieldname+i = $('#f' + i + 'name').val();
    var fieldspecify+i = $('#f' + i + 'specify').val();
    var fieldwidth+i = $('#f' + i + 'width').val();

        var data = {
            fieldname+i: fieldname+i,
            fieldspecify+i: fieldspecify+i,
            fieldwidth+i: fieldwidth+i
        };
}
```

My code in html:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
<div style="margin-top:25px;" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="f<?= $i; ?>name">Veld <?= $i; ?>: Wat is de vraag van het veld?</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="f<?= $i; ?>name"
               placeholder="Bijv. Wat is 1 + 2?"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="f<?= $i; ?>specify">Veld <?= $i; ?>: Soort veld</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="f<?= $i; ?>specify">
            <option disabled selected>Selecteer..</option>
            <option value="0">Tekst-input</option>
            <option value="1">Selecteer-input</option>
            <option value="2">Textarea-input</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="f<?= $i; ?>width">Veld <?= $i; ?>: Breedte</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="f<?= $i; ?>width">
            <option disabled selected>Selecteer..</option>
            <option value="0">25%</option>
            <option value="1">50%</option>
            <option value="2">75%</option>
            <option value="3">100%</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is: At what way can I bound variables in a way easier way than typing 30 lines.

Comment: Use a class instead of unique ids. Then you can just loop through them, traversing the DOM to find related elements. If you want a specific example, please add your HTML (or a shortened version of it) to the question.

Comment: you can use `var data = {};` and then `data[fieldname+i] = ...` etc for dynamic property names.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What about it? They can be used as `$('#f' + i + 'name').val()` like in the question or what do you mean?

Comment: I added my html

Comment: You can't dynamically create variable or object property names the way you are attempting.

Comment: You may also try to use [jQuery form serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to map all your form inputs automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class instead of unique ids. Then you can just loop through them using `map()` to return an object which holds the relevant key/value pairs which you can fill by traversing the DOM to find the elements related to the current row, something like this

```js
var data = $('.row').map(function() {
  var $row = $(this);
  return {
    fname: $row.find('.fname').val(),
    fspecify: $row.find('.fspecify').val(),
    fwidth: $row.find('.fwidth').val(),
  }
}).get();

console.log(data);
```

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label>Veld 1: Wat is de vraag van het veld?
        <input type="text" class="form-control fname" placeholder="Bijv. Wat is 1 + 2?"/>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Veld 1: Soort veld
      <select class="form-control fspecify">
        <option disabled selected>Selecteer..</option>
        <option value="0">Tekst-input</option>
        <option value="1">Selecteer-input</option>
        <option value="2">Textarea-input</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Veld 1: Breedte
      <select class="form-control fwidth">
        <option disabled selected>Selecteer..</option>
        <option value="0">25%</option>
        <option value="1">50%</option>
        <option value="2">75%</option>
        <option value="3">100%</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label>Veld 2: Wat is de vraag van het veld?
        <input type="text" class="form-control fname" placeholder="Bijv. Wat is 1 + 2?"/>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Veld 2: Soort veld
      <select class="form-control fspecify">
        <option disabled selected>Selecteer..</option>
        <option value="0">Tekst-input</option>
        <option value="1">Selecteer-input</option>
        <option value="2">Textarea-input</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Veld 2: Breedte
      <select class="form-control fwidth">
        <option disabled selected>Selecteer..</option>
        <option value="0">25%</option>
        <option value="1">50%</option>
        <option value="2">75%</option>
        <option value="3">100%</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note there's only 2 rows here, but this pattern will work infinitely.

Comment: Wrapping the label around the input limits your design options, doesn't it?

Comment: Woa. Thanks! Gonna try this one out

Comment: Potentially, but nothing a `<span>` can't fix :)

Comment: But you can't really style it with CSS properly anymore.

Comment: Am I correct that I can better give the current rows another classname. Now it takes all the other rows too (may be a mistake from me that I did not mention that)

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean, but if the `.row` selector is too greedy you can make it more restrictive, eg. `$('#parent .this-container-only .row')`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use counted variable names, i.e. variables with an running index in the name. This is always wrong (besides being syntactically invalid in your code).

If you have more than on thing of the same kind, use an array.

```
var fields = [], i;

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    fields.push({
        name: $('#f' + i + 'name').val(),
        specify: $('#f' + i + 'specify').val(),
        width: $('#f' + i + 'width').val()
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. Good to know that I can arrays the best in this way :D

Comment: The main take-away should be that you should never try to create variables named like `something1` to `somethingX`, neither explicitly nor implicitly. It's always wrong to to that, so try to get the idea out of your head as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use:

```
const els = document.getElementById("formId").elements;
```

This runs through all the fields / elements in the form. So using this, you could push the results into an object or do with it what you like.

This is the basis of the approach, but you can easily adapt it to your needs. Check the console to see the output.

**Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/9d2szx3k/

**HTML**

```
<form id="formId">
  <input type="text" value="Name" />
  <input type="password" value="Password" />
  <input type="tel" value="07888888888" />
  <select>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const els = document.getElementById("formId").elements;
console.log(els);

Array.from(els).forEach(el => {
    console.log(el.value);
});
```